# Eventlisteners not being added in the following js code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a todo app where I am dynamically generating tasks using javascript.[[image: (sample ouput)]]
I generate following equivalent html from js whenever I click on the add button:

```html
<div class="row datasection">
  <div class="todo">
    <div class="databox col s6 offset-s1 waves-effect">
      <p class="checkglyph1 checkglyph2">Task no 1</p>
      <a>
        <i class="material-icons checkglyph checkglyph1 checkglyph2 glyphcolor">check</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is whenever I click  event on the task created it should become yellow in colour.I have written the code to this. below.However it works fine only when there is one task created.If there is multiple then the last task works well but actionlistener on the first one does not seem to be working.I am not able to figure out where the code is breaking.

```js
var glyph= document.querySelectorAll(".glyphcolor");

for (var i = 0; i < glyph.length; i++) {
    glyph[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
    });
}
```

The actual snippet

```
//declaration
    var calendardata = document.getElementById('date1');
    var addbutton = document.querySelector('.addbutton');
    var todo = document.querySelector('.todo');
    addbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {

/* body to return the html */

      if (data.value) {
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <button> element
        newdiv.classList.add("databox", "col", "s6", "waves-effect");
        //console.log(newdiv);
        todo.appendChild(newdiv);
        //console.log(newdiv.parentNode);
        var newpar = document.createElement("p");
        newpar.classList.add("checkglyph1", "checkglyph2");
        var node = document.createTextNode(data.value + "." + "      " + 
        calendardata.value);
        var newa = document.createElement("a");
        newdiv.appendChild(newa)
        var newglyph = document.createElement("i");
        newglyph.classList.add("material-icons", "checkglyph", "checkglyph1", 
        "checkglyph2", "glyphcolor");
        var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
        newa.appendChild(newglyph);
        newglyph.append(node1);
        newpar.appendChild(node);
        newdiv.appendChild(newpar);
        data.value = "";
        calendardata.value = "";
        created = true;
      //  console.log("before glyh created");

        //code to perform action on the click of the tick symbol

        var glyph = document.querySelectorAll(".glyphcolor");
        var par = document.getElementsByClassName('checkglyph2');
        for (var i = 0; i < glyph.length; i++) {
    //console.log("Inside the loop");
    glyph[i].addEventListener('click', function.bind(event) {
        this.classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
        //console.log('Inside the click');
        //console.log(i);
    });


}   

      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that everytime you click on ".addbutton", you're going through all of the ".glyphcolor"s element's in your DOM and adding a new onclick event listener. The last one created will work, but the others will have multiple event listeners repeated (yes, this is possible). So, when you click on an element that has two events telling it to toggle the "checkglyph1" class, it will do it twice. And of course, it will not change at all. You can easily see this happening, because all the odd elements in your page must work (they will toggle the class by odd times), while the even ones must not.

This can be corrected by adding the event listener directly on the element when you create it on the page. The code below must work fine:

```
//declaration
var calendardata = document.getElementById('date1');
var addbutton = document.querySelector('.addbutton');
var todo = document.querySelector('.todo');

addbutton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (data.value) {
    var newdiv = document.createElement("div"); // Create a <button> element
    newdiv.classList.add("databox", "col", "s6", "waves-effect");
    //console.log(newdiv);
    todo.appendChild(newdiv);
    //console.log(newdiv.parentNode);
    var newpar = document.createElement("p");
    newpar.classList.add("checkglyph1", "checkglyph2");
    var node = document.createTextNode(data.value + "." + "      " + 
    calendardata.value);
    var newa = document.createElement("a");
    newdiv.appendChild(newa)
    var newglyph = document.createElement("i");
    newglyph.classList.add("material-icons", "checkglyph", "checkglyph1", 
    "checkglyph2", "glyphcolor");
    var node1 = document.createTextNode("check");
    newa.appendChild(newglyph);
    newglyph.append(node1);
    newpar.appendChild(node);
    newdiv.appendChild(newpar);
    data.value = "";
    calendardata.value = "";
    created = true;

    newglyph.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Just to prevent non desired effects of click

        newglyph.classList.toggle('checkglyph1');
    }
   }
 }
```

And just small clarifications: you don't need the "bind" in your actual code.

```
glyph[i].addEventListener('click', function.bind(event) { // just type function(event)
   this.classList.toggle('checkglyph1');...
```

Comment: If you see my code I have placed the variable declaration for glyphcolor and  the eventlistener immediately after the code to create the task.Can you please tell me how the code goes because as per my understanding after creating the task it will get all the glyph class and in the loop it will add an event listener.I am a newbie so can you please tell me how the code works if my understanding is wrong.@bruno.

Comment: @leo
Well, after debugging your code, I can tell you exactly why your code is not working. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening that when they other tasks are created they aren't being collected in the Node Collection, thus they have no event listener. What you can do is instead add the event listener to the container and change whichever item that was clicked in:

```js
document.querySelector('ul').addEventListener('click', changeClass);
document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', addLi);

function changeClass(e){
  e.target.closest('li').classList.toggle('checkglyph1');
}

function addLi(e){
  const new_li = document.createElement('li');
  new_li.textContent = document.querySelectorAll('li').length + 1;
  new_li.classList.add('checkglyph1');
  document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(new_li);
}
```

```css
li:not(.checkglyph1) {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Add li</button>
<ul>
  <li class="checkglyph1">1</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">2</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1 red">3</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">4</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">5</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">6</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">7</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">8</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">9</li>
  <li class="checkglyph1">10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but I am adding eventlistener in the loop right. 
   glyph[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {

Comment: Yes but in that moment only one of the elements exist, what you would need to do if you want to add an event listener to each of the elements ( which is not a good performance idea) is that when you add the new element, you will need to declare against the query selector all together all the elements in there and then run again the loop, as you have it is correct but not complete

Comment: I did not understand when you said declare against query selector.correct me when wrong.my logic is that it selects all query with class as glyphcolor and then using the loop it adds an event listener of click to each of that.So next time when I click it should work.

Comment: Yes it selectes all the elements with the class at the moment of being called, but it will not add any new element that matches the class in the future, so since you are adding more elements with js it won't work for those new elements, unless you store the elements again with query selector and loop over again to give them the event listener. That's why is easier to add the event listener to the container of such elements